# How do I change Eclipse to use spaces instead of tabs?

Tags: eclipse, formatting, tabs, whitespace

By default [Eclipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29) indents with a hard tab character. How do I change it to spaces?

Comment: Check [the following link](http://rakesh.sankar-b.com/2011/08/22/convert-tabs-to-spaces-in-eclipse-and-file-in-linux/) that I had wrote which contains the steps to convert tabs to spaces in Eclipse and also in Linux VI editor.

Comment: related: [How can I get Eclipse to insert tabs instead of spaces?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2636589/how-can-i-get-eclipse-to-insert-tabs-instead-of-spaces-for-java-content-assist).

Comment: @i3ensays because tabs are presented differently in different editors or environments whereas spaces are always consistent.

Comment: @mmmdreg exactly my point. spaces are rigid and wasteful. Using tabs gives freedom to the viewer to configure their editor as desired. I like my tabs to display as 2 spaces, my colleague 4. This is not possible without use of tabs. My colleague here, and I, battle spaces  when we each format in our respective editor; tabs are not an issue; this is why they were invented (I suspect).

Comment: @i3ensays amen, brother! I've been trying to make people understand this concept for over 10 years (http://www.rizzoweb.com/java/tabs-vs-spaces.html). What really alarms me is that, as programmers, you'd think everyone would understand the concept of abstractions (a tab is an abstraction of code indentation, while a fixed number of spaces is a hard-coded implementation) - but alas, it seems that many programmers can't see the abstraction here.

Comment: @i3ensays Your team should have a coding standard that clearly states how code is formatted. This would save time by preventing the battles you mention. You should adopt one asap but that standard will 100% certainly state that tabs are never to be used because this holy war was won by the "space people" ages ago so a standard won't help you. Aside from alignment issues one of the biggest reasons for spaces only is that revision control tools and code reviewers won't have to deal with this issue. I started on your side of this battle 20 years ago but eventually learned to embrace the space.

Comment: The reason is that people will inevitably end up with combinations of tabs and spaces and in some editors the code will not display correctly. If everyone just uses spaces then this is never a problem.

Comment: Hi everybody!  I'm the original Asker of The Question.  Could someone with enough Hit Points close down the comments on this question?  The actual question has been very thoroughly answered, and now it has devolved into re-litigating the tabs vs. spaces war.  Tucker Carlson pretty much laid that argument to rest a few years ago on Crossfire.  The correct answer is: tax cuts.

Comment: Amazing to see the last holdouts for "tab faction". Yes, spaces won. Get on with the program. Savings in bytes have not been the issue since 80s, and none of the other benefits really matter enough to offset problems caused by having to treat tabs as Very Special Little Characters.

Comment: @StaxMan if spaces had obtained a decisive win, then I would not now be looking up this answer and figuring out how to reconfigure eclipse to use spaces over tabs - to comply with my team's policy.  In a decisive space win, eclipse would just use spaces by default.  IOW the battle rages on.

Comment: @emory alas. Right you are. Eclipse defaults are one of my pet peeves. Then again, IdeaJ also has its own idiosyncratic defaults, like "magically expanding lines".

Comment: For JavaScript specific case, see also https://stackoverflow.com/q/8993295/912046 which redirected me to here.

Comment: @emory this question and your team's policy show that spaces won. Probably, only people workin on Eclipse dev team use tabs. Maybe even they don't.

Comment: I asked this question in 2011, before my elementary school child was born. Before java introduced try-with-resources. Every few months I get an email saying that somebody commented on it. Does beating a dead horse require more or less SO reputation than closing the question?

Comment: The problem has to do with the use of the backspace key.  If I have a line that goes

position->count->comment
then I expect that if I put the text in as
beginning->4->once upon a time

Answer (score 1305, accepted):

#### Java Editor

1. Click **Window** » **Preferences**
2. Expand **Java** » **Code Style**
3. Click **Formatter**
4. Click the **Edit** button
5. Click the **Indentation** tab
6. Under **General Settings**, set **Tab policy** to: `Spaces only`
7. Click **OK** ad nauseam to apply the changes.

[***Note***: If necessary save profile with a new name as the default profile cannot be overwritten.]

#### Default Text Editor

Before version 3.6:

```
Window->Preferences->Editors->Text Editors->Insert spaces for tabs
```

Version 3.6 and later:

1. Click **Window** » **Preferences**
2. Expand **General** » **Editors**
3. Click **Text Editors**
4. Check **Insert spaces for tabs**
5. Click **OK** ad nauseam to apply the changes.

Note that the default text editor is used as the basis for many non-Java editors in Eclipse. It's astonishing that this setting wasn't available until 3.3.

#### C / C++

1. Click **Window** » **Preferences**
2. Expand **C/C++** » **Code Style**
3. Click **Formatter**
4. Click the **New** button to create a new profile, then **OK** to continue
5. Click the **Indentation** tab
6. Under **General Settings**, set **Tab policy** to: `Spaces only`
7. Click **OK** ad nauseam to apply the changes.

#### HTML

1. Click **Window** » **Preferences**
2. Expand **Web** » **HTML Files**
3. Click **Editor**
4. Under **Formatting**, select the **Indent using spaces** radio button
5. Click **OK** to apply the changes.

#### CSS

Follow the same instructions for HTML, but select **CSS Files** instead of **HTML Files**.

#### JSP

By default, JSP files follow the formatting preferences for HTML Files.

#### XML

XML files spacing is configured in Preferences.

1. Click **Window** » **Preferences**
2. Expand **XML** » **XML Files**
3. Click **Editor**
4. Select **Indent using spaces**
5. You can specify the **Indentation size** if needed: number of spaces to indent.

Comment: For those who have MyEclipse installed or any other IDE built on top of Eclipse, you may have another editor overriding your settings. This was the case for MyEclipse and JavaScript. I had my "Insert spaces for tabs" setting enabled in Text Editors, but tabs were still being used instead of spaces. I was about to call it a day and write it off as a bug, but then I saw a second editor for JavaScript (*.js ) files in the "Associated Editors" list.

Comment: This might be a helpful hint, but if you experience the same behavior, check if the file has any other associated editors because they may be overriding your settings. To do so, goto 

    Window > Preferences > General > Editors > File Associations > then look for the file extension which is ruining your day in that list > click it and look at the Associated Editors list below

Comment: For JavaScript, I saw both Text Editor and MyEclipse JavaScript Editor which was flagged as the default. So one of two things can be done here, you can either set Text Editor to be your default or you can update the MyEclipse JavaScript Editor settings. I opted to do the latter and went to:

    Window > Preferences > MyEclipse > Files and Editors > JavaScript > Code Style > Formatter > Edit... > Tab policy:

Hope this helps!

Comment: For XML I had no associated edotor but I had to go to Window > Preferences > XML > XML Files > Editor

Comment: for existing Java file press Ctrl-A to highlight everything and then Ctrl-I to apply current indents. Otherwise existing tabs will prevent spaces in new lines created with Enter. It also replaces existing tabs with spaces.

Comment: @topchef That's exactly what was happening to me! Had all the settings as described but when I hit tab or Ctrl+I on a new line it gives the hard tabs. But as you said, the existing tabs were the culprit. Thanks :)

Comment: In Eclipse 3.7.1, the first line should specify that "spaces only" is a dropdown menu option.

Comment: @topchef The option you are talking about is editor specific. e.g. its available for javascript editor of [Eclipse web tool platform](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/) (in my case), It is not available to all file type. Specially when I have cfeclise for ColdFusion.

Comment: For C/C++, one has to also change C/C++->"Code Style". This is by far the most annoying in this otherwise great software.

Comment: I'm amazed how many people don't understand the value of tabs and insist on replacing them with spaces (see my comments to OP question).

Comment: To be more detailed, for C/C++ and Ecplipse 3.6 or later, the second step was: Window > Preferences > C/C++ > Code Style > Formatter > New, then choose any Profile name, ensure that `Open the edit dialog now` is enabled, hit `OK`, then under the `Indentation` tab, you'll see `Tab Policy`.  Set it to `Spaces Only`.

Comment: For the Mac, Preferences are under the "Eclipse" menu option.

Comment: Any instructions for scala?  I made the changes in the general editor and they do not seem to have gone into effect for my scala files

Comment: C/C++: tabs in multi-line `#define` macros will not get replaced by Eclipse's auto-formatter, presumably because of the escaped newlines. Doing a regex find/replace of tabs with spaces is necessary.

Comment: @John +1. I was baffled because I had configured seemingly everything to use spaces instead of tabs, but my JSP files were still formatting incorrectly. This answer and your comment pointed me towards the HTML specific editor...

Comment: When I follow these instructions, the "Ok" button gets grayed out, so I can't use them. Any ideas why?

Comment: Setting it for general editor should set it for all editors, Eclipse settings are insane.

Comment: Yet another place where these kind of settings could be overwritting the "spaces for tabs" behaviour is in the "Project Specific Settings". It happened to me in a legacy project where the project settings were commited to the repository. In my case, I had to change the settings in Project > Properties > Java Code Style > Formatter. It should be analogous to the other editors and settings described in this answer.

Comment: This is how we got it to work in STS also based on eclipse 3.8

Comment: YAML in 2023 with Wild Web Developer?

Answer (score 158):

For the default text editor:

- **General** » **Editors** » **Text Editors** » `Insert spaces for tabs` *(check it)*

---

For PHP:

- **PHP** » **Code Style** » **Formatter** » `Tab policy` *(choose "spaces")*
- **PHP** » **Code Style** » **Formatter** » `Indentation size` *(set to 4)*

---

For CSS:

- **Web** » **CSS** » **Editor** » `Indent using spaces` *(select it)*
- **Web** » **CSS** » **Editor** » `Indentation size` *(set to 4)*

---

For HTML:

- **Web** » **HTML** » **Editor** » `Indent using spaces` *(select it)*
- **Web** » **HTML** » **Editor** » `Indentation size` *(set to 4)*

---

For XML:

- **XML** » **XML Files** » **Editor** » `Indent using spaces` *(select it)*
- **XML** » **XML Files** » **Editor** » `Indentation size` *(set to 4)*

---

For Javascript:

- **Javascript** » **Preferences** » **Code Style** » **Formatter** » **Edit** » `Indentation` *(choose "spaces only")*
- Rename the formatter settings profile to save it

---

For Java:

- **Java** » **Preferences** » **Code Style** » **Formatter** » **Edit** » `Indentation` *(choose "spaces only")*
- Rename the formatter settings profile to save it

Comment: I see no Web or Javascript options in the root of Preferences (I do have a Web Perspective available, though) and I want to set tabs as spaces for just html, css, and javascript files.  I'm on Helios Eclipse for Java Developers, any idea how I can get that option?

Comment: These settings are what I see in Eclipse PDT (PHP Development Tools). Eclipse PDT is built on Eclipse WTP (Web Tools Platform), which includes JavaScript Development Tools (JSDT) and Source Editing of various web formats. This is probably what you're missing.

Comment: +1 for the Java stuff which is absolutely necessary because its default settings override the general text editor settings.

Comment: for C, Code Style -> Formatter -> Edit -> Indentation -> General Settings -> Tab Policy

Comment: Not suit with **Eclipse PDT Luna 4.4**

Comment: Also be careful to update specific other editors that have their own formatter e.g. the Ant file editor vs the XML editor and so on.

Comment: Thanks! This works well in Mars. It's disappointing that the Text Editor options exist yet do nothing!

Answer (score 38):

From [changing tabs to spaces in eclipse](http://blog.dotkam.com/2007/03/21/changing-tabs-to-spaces-in-eclipse/):

**Window** » **Preferences** » **Java** » **Code Style** » **Formatter** » **Edit** » `Indentation` *(choose "Spaces Only")*

Comment: for XML , xml-->xml files-->editor, then select indent using spaces, indentation size 2.

Answer (score 27):

For **CDT**:

- *Go to* **Window/Preference** » **C/C++** » **Code Style** » **Formatter** » **New**
- *Create a new one because the built in profile can not be changed*
- **MyProfile** *(choose one name for the profile)*
- **Indentation** » `Tab Policy` *(choose Spaces only)*

Answer (score 25):

Just a quick tip for people stumbling across this thread; there is **one more place** where this setting can also be set, in your project!

Eclipse supports project-specific settings, and some projects will use their own, un-managed tabs/spaces settings, which won't show up anywhere except the current project Properties.

This can be managed through:

- Right-Click current Project in **Package Explorer**
- **Properties** » **Java Code Style**
- Turn *off* all the project-specific options

This will generally only be an issue if you import someone else's code into your Eclipse.

Answer (score 23):

**For Default Editor:**

**Window** » **Preferences** » **Editors** » **Text Editors** » `Insert spaces for tabs`

[image]

**For Java editor**

**Window** » **Preferences** » **Java** » **Code Style** » **Formatter** » **Edit** » **Indentation** » `Tab policy` *"Spaces Only"*

[image]

Comment: I have set it to tabs only.

Answer (score 10):

When I faced this problem I had "use spaces for tabs" set to true everywhere I could find, and yet I was still getting tabs. It ended up being because tabs were used elsewhere in the file and it was trying to do smart indentation or something frustrating.

It was resolved by selecting the entire contents of the file and pressing, on a mac, `command+shift+f`. This applies the given formatting to a file. I do not know the same keybinding on windows, but give that a try. At that point I begin getting the expected behavior.

Comment: For a more modular fix to this problem, the user can also do a Find/Replace for `\t` (make sure regular expressions are enabled) and replace with the desired amount of space characters

Comment: The key for formatting file on Windows is quite similar - `Ctrl+Shift+F`.

Answer (score 8):

Go to *Window* -> *Preferences* and type *tab* as the search text (which will display a dialog like below):

[image]

Go to the highlighted sections to change the tab policy. For the *Editor* settings it is mostly *Indent using spaces* (also shown above).

For *Formatter* settings you need to edit the active profile and update *Tab policy* (available under `*Indentation* -> *General settings*:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Be sure to check the java formater since it overwrites the **"insert spaces for tabs"** setting. Go to:

`Java->Code Style"->Formatter->Edit->Identation`

Note: you will need to create a custom format to be able to save your configuration.

Answer (score 6):

**Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers, Version: Helios Service Release 2**

You need to create new profile by pressing New button inside "Window->Preferences->Code Style"

Go to Indentation tab and select "Tab policy = Space only"

---

**Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers, Version: Kepler Service Release 1**

Follow the path below to create new profile: 
"Window > Preferences > C/C++ > Code Style > Formatter"

Go to Indentation tab and select "Tab policy = Space only"

Comment: That policy needs a warning in it: "Space only unless previous line has tabs!"

Answer (score 5):

I found the solution this problem very simple and which works always. It is change the eclipse setting file.

For example (change HTML indentation size):

---

1. Found `org.eclipse.wst.html.core.prefs` file which should be in `your_workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/`
2. Add/Change to line in file:

```
indentationChar=space

indentationSize=4
```

Comment: On Ubuntu 14.04.03 LTS and eclipse 4.5 I cannot change the identation size is always locked and not changeable. This solved my problem.

Answer (score 5):

### In eclipse format xml:

#### For tab:

```xml
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.tabulation.char" value="tab"/>
```

#### For space:

```xml
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.tabulation.char" value="space"/>
```

Answer (score 4):

In Eclipse go to **Window** » **Preferences** then search for **Formatter**.

You will see various bold links, 
click on each bold link
and set it to `use spaces` instead of `tabs`.

In the java formatter link, you have to edit the profile
and select the tab policy, `spaces only` in indentation tab

Answer (score 4):

Window->Preferences->Java->Code Style->Formatter->Edit->Indentation = "Spaces Only"

Answer (score 3):

Don't miss Tab policy for both of 
  * Spaces only
  * Use spaces to indent wrapped lines

I checked only the latter thing and left the Combobox as Tabs Only which kept failing CheckStyle..
FYI, I'm talking about Preferences > Java > Formatter > Edit...

Answer (score 3):

Here is a way using the Eclipse Formatter:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Also consider using an .editorconfig file: https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/editorconfig-eclipse.
Someone not using Eclipse may also benefit from this, in the worst case it can serve as a guideline.
NOTE: I will not enter the tabs vs space wars but use spaces FTW :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can definitely use XML file to configure your formatter of the coding style. The formatter file helps you to have the same coding style and guidelines across your team members.

Adding these below setting variables would have `a tab= 2 spaces` and convert to space even you probably use `Tab` shorthand key when coding using **Eclipse**.

```
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.tabulation.size" value="2"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.tabulation.char" value="space"/>    
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.use_tabs_only_for_leading_indentations" value="yes"/>
```

Best,

Answer (score 1):

Using [EditorConfig](https://editorconfig.org/) is a solution

1. Install [editor config Eclipse plugin](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/editorconfig-eclipse)
2. Create an `.editorconfig` with following content:

   ```ini
   root = true

   [*]
   indent_style = space
   indent_size = 4
   insert_final_newline = true
   charset = utf-8
   ```

You can do even more as changing the line ending style to `LF` using `end_of_line = lf`

This also prepares usage of spaces in [IntelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50930969/873282) and [VS.Code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47357322/873282).

Answer (score 0):

In eclipse mars (EE) on Mac OS X, the only way I could find this in the preferences was to open the Preference dialog and type Formatter, then select Java->Code Style->Formatter.

**Java->Code Style has no access to Formatter!**

Answer (score 0):

And don't forget the **ANT editor**

For some reason Ant Editor does not show up in the search results for `'tab'` or `'spaces'` so can be missed.

Under **Windows** > **Preferences**

- **Ant** » **Editor** » **Formatter** » `Tab size:` *(set to 4)*
- **Ant** » **Editor** » **Formatter** » `Use tab character instead of spaces` *(uncheck it)*

Answer (score 0):

- Click Window » Preferences
- Expand Java » Code Style
- Click Formatter
- click new
- Select the profile name
- Click ok
- Click the Edit button
- Click the Indentation tab
- Under General Settings, set Tab policy to: Spaces only
- Click OK.

Answer (score 0):

As an augmentation to the other answers, on Mac OS X, the "Preferences" menu is under Eclipse, **not** Window (unlike Windows/Linux Eclipse distributions).  Everything else is still the same as pointed out by other answers past this point.

IE: Java Formatter available under:

```
Eclipse >      | # Not Window!
Preferences >  |
Java >         |
Code Style >   |
Formatter      |
```

From here, edit the formatter and the tab policy can be set under "Indentation".