# Indenting with tabs in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I have tried every suggestion I could find, but I can't get my code to get indented with tabs.

java -> code style -> formatter -> edit -> indentation -> "use spaces to indent wrapped lines" is unchecked and policy is set to tab only.

general -> editors -> text editors -> "insert spaces for tabs" is unchecked.

Still eclipse replaces my tabs with spaces and does auto-indentation with spaces.

I am slowly going insane

(eclipse luna)

Comment: Did you format the code after these changes. I mean Select All (Ctrl+A) and format (Ctrl+Shft+F)

Comment: Yes, I did. Still, spaces instead of tabs

Comment: "I am slowly going insane" - You're becoming a real programmer then.

Comment: Which editor? What are you trying to edit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my question can be found here : [How can I get Eclipse to insert tabs instead of spaces for Java content assist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2636589/how-can-i-get-eclipse-to-insert-tabs-instead-of-spaces-for-java-content-assist)

It appears to be a bug in Eclipse, currently.