# Inserting Spaces Instead of Tabs in ALL Files

Tags: eclipse, jsp, tabs, spaces

Our unit testing setup makes sure you use spaces instead of tabs in all files, including .jsp and jspx. I have set this option for the general editor but the jsp editor does not recognize/see this option and still continues to use tabs instead of spaces.

Is there a way to force the jsp editor to insert spaces instead of tabs?

:)

Comment: I'm guessing you already saw this post then... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/407929/how-do-i-change-eclipse-to-use-spaces-instead-of-tabs

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Go to *Window > Preferences* and set option *Indent using spaces* in the following categories:

- *Web > HTML files > Editor* (covers JSP)
- *XML > XML files > Editor* (covers JSPX and Facelets)
- *Web > CSS files > Editor* (you'd like to cover this as well)

Comment: For some reason, my Eclipse (Indigo, Build id: 20110916-0149) uses the HTML settings instead of the XML settings for JSPX pages, even though in the settings it indicates that it will use the XML settings.

Comment: You can change the default editor via rightclick, *Open With*.