# How do I change Eclipse to use spaces instead of tabs in Javascript editor?

Tags: javascript, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, jslint

I use the Eclipse JavaScript plugin, I have my text editor settings to "insert spaces as tabs" this works fine until I select a block of code and tab it or shift tab it, run JSLint and AARGghh! "Mixed spaces and tabs." is there something I am missing, is this possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I change Eclipse to use spaces instead of tabs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/407929/how-do-i-change-eclipse-to-use-spaces-instead-of-tabs)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I am not exactly sure where you set the editor property "insert spaces as tabs". To set the tab policy you need to go to `Window > Preferences > Javascript > Code Style > Formatter`, create a new profile, edit it and set the Tab policy to "spaces only". Now when using the tab key spaces are inserted.

Comment: very helpful Thanks!

Comment: maybe is a different Eclipse version but in my Version: 2021-12 (4.22.0) Build id: 20211202-1639 this menu doesn't exists.
Maybe is
Windows / preferences / web / client-side javascript / formatter
but for me it doesn't work: in my js,  "tabs" dont turn into "spaces"