# Checkstyle : always receive File contains tab characters (this is the first instance)

Tags: java, eclipse, checkstyle

I'm using Checkstyle for Java in Eclipse IDE. I don't know in every java file, at second line, I always receive warning in Checkstyle : (although I'm pretty sure that I don't press tab key)

> File contains tab characters (this is the first instance).

```
public class Percolation {
    private boolean[][] grid;
...
}
```

When I have typed : `public class Percolation {`, press enter, Eclipse will make an indent for me, after that, I type `private boolean[][] grid;`. But, I still receive this warning.

Please tell me how to fix this. (I don't want to turn off this warning, because this is a must. Another people will check again my file).

Thanks :)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In eclipse, go to Preferences > General > Editors > Text Editors
and check the box for "Insert spaces for tabs".  Then it will indent with spaces instead of tabs.

Comment: Sorry. I have changed to this option, but still receive this notice :(

Comment: Do you have the problem in new source files or in ones that already had the problem?  For existing files you will need to re-indent them: select all of the text, then from the context menu, Source > Correct Identation.

Comment: I have problem in source that already had problem. I have selected all, correct indentation, and recheck again, it still has this warning :(

Comment: I deleted some first lines of code and typed again, still no improve

Comment: After above setting, eclipse's autoformatting ctrl+shift+F replaced tabs with spaces itself then problem solved.

Comment: Unfortunately, I stil have the problem. I have hundreds of [ERROR] MyClass.java[808:1] (whitespace) FileTabCharacter: Line contains a tab character. I have Checkstyle configuration plugin for M2Eclipse 1.0.0.201503101518 com.basistech.m2e.code.quality.checkstyle.feature.f‌​eature.group : Eclipse Checkstyle Plug-in 6.11.1.201510102004 net.sf.eclipsecs.feature.group eclipse-cs.sf.net So what I have to do?

Answer (score 27):

**step 1** In eclipse, Preference > Java > Code Style > Formatter. Edit the Active profile.(If you don't wish to edit the built-in profile , create a new  profile). Under "Active profile:" there is a drop down dialogue box .. beside it, click "Edit..." which opens up the edit dialog  box. Under the "Indention" tab, you'll find **Tab Policy**. Change the Tab Policy from **Mixed to Space only** & apply the changes.

**step 2** Back to your Eclipse Perspective, navigate via the menu bar: Source > **Format Element** (not "Format") and save.

Run checkstyle you won't find "File Tab Character: File contains tab characters (this is the first instance)." warning anymore.

To visualize the difference by enabling whitespace character that you'll find in tool bar.

Comment: Its tab policy not tag policy

Answer (score 5):

another possibility is find and replace:
- copy a tab
- Got to Find and Replace Window
find: paste the tab
replace: type 4 whitespaces (or number of whitespaces a tab consists of)
-> replaceAll

Answer (score 4):

For Java code:

**step 1** In eclipse, `Preference > Java > Code Style > Formatter.` Create a new profile and initialize it with default profile. There is a drop down dialogue box .. beside it, click "Edit..." which opens up the edit dialog box. Under the "Indention" tab, you'll find Tab Policy. Change the Tab Policy from Mixed to "Space only" & apply the changes.

**step 2** Correct Indentation of your code by `ctrl+I`. It will replace Tab with Space.

Answer (score 3):

To fix this Navigate to `Preferences > Java > Code Style > Formatter.` 
Then click on `New > give name for the formatter > click on ok`.

[image]

Once you complete this step, on the automatically popped up window which is the formatter you created, click on `indentation > tap policy > select space only`.
*Or if you come back later time you could click on edit and follow the same step.*
[image]

in the indentation size I prefer to `put 4 > click apply and close.`

After that `right click` on the class file you want to format > `source > format.` 
This will cause the indentation to be spaces instead of tabs.

Answer (score 2):

I was also facing the problem but I got the solutions.

**Step 1** : Go to Window > Preferences >  Checkstyle.

**Step 2** : In the right side You will see the Global Check Configurations. There you will find that **Two** configurations are available. Select the configuration with **Eclipse** and click on **Set as Default** button and click on **OK**.

Hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

For Java Editor

Click Window » Preferences
Expand Java » Code Style
Click Formatter
Click the Edit button
Click the Indentation tab
Under General Settings, set Tab policy to: Spaces only
Click OK ad nauseum to apply the changes.

For other editors refer here [How do I change Eclipse to use spaces instead of tabs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/407929/how-do-i-change-eclipse-to-use-spaces-instead-of-tabs)

Answer (score -2):

Simply fixed that style issue (triggered by scalaStyle) by removing TAB with SPACE indent :)