# Eclipse HotKey: How to switch between indenting levels based with spaces?

Tags: java, eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

Switching from Tabs to Spaces in our Java project, I am looking for the Eclipse shortcut *so basic that I can't remember it* which allows, on a given line, to move the caret to the next "group of spaces".

With tabs, it is pretty easy, because they count as a single character, so just using arrow keys is okay, but with spaces, if, let's say, the indentation level is based on 4 spaces, Left or Right arrows must be pushed down 4 times before accessing the next indentation level.

Thanks!

Comment: So basically you need an hotkey to move the caret by 4 space a time without pressing arrow keys 4 times.. right?

Comment: Yes, I do. Eclipse does have this feature builtin, I saw it before, but can't remember it...

Comment: Are you indenting with spaces manually or you configured eclipse? Try to give a look at this [how do i change eclipse to use spaces instead of tabs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/407929/how-do-i-change-eclipse-to-use-spaces-instead-of-tabs). If you configured it with spaces, i think the indent line will work as intended.

Comment: No, still not a shortcut I look for...

Comment: Is it Alt+left-arrow and Alt+right-arrow that you are looking for?

Comment: Hehe, no, still not, this moves from a Tab Editor to another, while I search the shortcut for moving (left or right) from a "Tabulation character" or "X-space in a row" (X being set in Eclipse settings)

Answer (score 0):

1. Default indentation: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>
2. Right indentation: <kbd>Tab</kbd>
3. Left: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>