# Eclipse code not indent properly in git

Tags: java, git, bitbucket

I write code in eclipse and indent it properly there. It also looks fine in Eclipse. But when I push that code in github(I am using bitbucket) and then go to git. I see that in github(I am using bitbucket) the indentation is totally messed up.

Any solution for this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/407929/how-do-i-change-eclipse-to-use-spaces-instead-of-tabs

Comment: What do you mean by "go to git"? Are you using `git show` `gitweb` or something else to view your code "in git"?

Comment: git means - github(I am using bitbucket). Sorry !!

Comment: @APaul Do you able to solve it? Even I am facing the same issue and I am using  Eclipse + Bitbucket.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have a mixture of tabs and spaces and the tab stop settings (number of spaces that equals one tab) in git (did you mean GitHub) are different than what you have set in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes to tweak these settings.

.java  text diff=java trailing-space space-before-tab -indent-with-non-tab