# Java code indentation mixed space and tabs

Tags: java, eclipse, code-formatting

Tab and spaces are mix used on same projects.

I need to code indentation but do not replace tab with spaces and vice versa. I only need to indent code (new indentation with space or tabs does not matter).

Eclipse IDE is used but plugin or other tools are welcome.

P.S I know that at same project same white space strategy (tab or white) using is better.

As an example \t --> tab   \b --> space. I think need to some property that how many space equals to tab 1 character. For our example 4.

Before

```
void foo() {
\b\b\btest1();  // 3 spaces
\ttest2();  // 1 tab
}
```

After

```
void foo() {
\b\b\b\btest1();  // 4 space (1 extra space to be indent correctly)
\ttest2();  // 1 tab  (do not change tab char with spaces because of that has correct indentation)
}
```

Comment: I really have a tough time understanding your question. Eclipse indents your code as you type, or you can manually call the formatter using CTRL+SHIFT+F (also works for selections). You can either set it to spaces or tabs and have an auto save action to fix the whole file if you want that.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse, in the `Project` menu, go into `Properties` -> `Java Code Style` and press the `Edit` button to edit your current profile.
In this window, you can configure your indentation parameters.

To apply them, in your code press `ctrl + a` to select your code then press `ctrl + i` to format it according to your parameters

Comment: If codes indent with space, after CTRL+A & CTRL+i combination, space replace with tabs. I don't want to this. I want to be stay as space.

Comment: In the same window, you can specify 'Spaces only' for the 'Tab policy'.

Comment: If this can't solve your problem, i may have misunderstood your question. If so, could you provide an example or somethig?

Comment: I add an example to question, i hope more clear to being understand.

Comment: OK, I understand better your question now. I don't think what you want is posible in Eclipse (even with a plugin). But if I may ask, why do you want to keep the actual mixed indentation? I don't think it's a good practice.

Comment: If possible, do not change to file (history). Easy to compare with history. Yes, i know some diff tool support that ignoring whitespace, but in git, file has been changed but actually nothing is changed.

Comment: Oh ok, I understand now. Maybe you could reindent your code correctly and try to configure Git to ignore spaces and tabs. There are some posts about it on SO.

Comment: Reindenting existing code is extremely painful to the people who need to merge your changes into the same file in the branches they're working on.

Answer (score 0):

There is an active question how to reconfigure Eclipse for spaces at [How do I change Eclipse to use spaces instead of tabs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/407929/873282). This is very tedious.

I also encountered this issue at a project. I did not want to deal with huge IDE setup. Editorconfig is a solution

1. Install [editor config Eclipse plugin](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/editorconfig-eclipse)
2. Create an `.editorconfig` with following content:

   ```ini
   root = true

   [*]
   indent_style = space
   indent_size = 4
   insert_final_newline = true
   charset = utf-8
   ```

You can do even more as changing the line ending style to `LF` using `end_of_line = lf`

This way, also users of IntelliJ and VS.Code can have the same configuration when editing the files.