# Eclipse indents new line with tabs instead of spaces

Tags: eclipse, tabs, liferay, whitespace, liferay-ide

I've followed all the suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/407929/how-do-i-change-eclipse-to-use-spaces-instead-of-tabs).

When I press `return`, I get a new line that is indented with *tabs* instead of *spaces*.

If I backspace to clear the tabs, and then press TAB a series of times, **it correctly indents with spaces**.

I'm pretty sure I have all my settings set up correctly.  I created a new `Code Style > Formatter` policy for every language in the project, and specified to always use spaces.  It seems as though these settings are partially active (ex: when I press `tab`), but inactive when I use `return`.  I tried restarting Eclipse.  I'll try restarting the computer now...

I'm using Mac OS X 10.9.2 and a Liferay Developer Studio (1.6.3.v201312111844) version of Eclipse (not sure which Eclipse build its based on though).

Can anyone think of another setting/solution to ensure that newlines are created with spaces instead of tabs?  I recently saw http://editorconfig.org/, and I'm wondering if there's some interference.

Thanks for any suggestions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the file has existing lines that are using tabs, then <kbd>Enter</kbd> will respect that and try to create new lines in a similar way (see [this comment by topchef](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/407929/how-do-i-change-eclipse-to-use-spaces-instead-of-tabs#comment6565490_408449) for a solution). Also, it could be something in Liferay Studio's proprietary settings is overriding Eclipse standard preferences ([as suggested by user John](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/407929/how-do-i-change-eclipse-to-use-spaces-instead-of-tabs#comment2204109_408449)).

Keep in mind that each type of editor in Eclipse can have its own preferences and perhaps that's what you're running into here. You can try to find them all by opening Preferences and searching for "indent" in the search field. That will show all the preferences pages where indentation can be configured.

[image]

Also note that the **Formatter** settings don't have any affect on as-you-type formatting; that's for when you select a file or group of files or part of a file and choose **Source** > **Format** from the menu.

Comment: Which settings control the 'as-you-type' settings?  I've changed everything I've found, maybe I missed something.

I did Source > Format the whole file, saved it, restarted, etc.  It's still not working..

Comment: See the additions I made to my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the screen.  I found those "Typing" settings, and they're set appropriately.  I reformatted my code and there are no tabs.  It still doesn't work - but I'll give up for now

Comment: Whew! Got it. Just as I was about to give up, here's a potential tip for anyone else who finds this:

Go to `General > Editors > File Associations` to figure out which editors are enabled for various file types.

I had an Aptana editor active, which had its own Tabs/Spaces setting.  I changed literally 5-6 different `Editor > Formatter` settings before I found the right one.

Comment: @E-Riz It looks like the **Formatter** settings do affects as-you-type formatting. Eclipse was auto indenting a new line when I hit _return_ using a four-space tab. Once I modified the settings in the **Formatter**, Eclipse started indenting by two spaces. This is on _Eclipse Neon_. This should be rechecked as I was messing with a number of settings.

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with this with my editing.  I found out an interesting thing:

***Eclipse editor is taking indentation character cues from the previous line!***

If you go to the end of a line indented with the `tab` character and `press enter` to add code, it uses the `tab` to indent the new line.  If the existing line was indented with `spaces`, it uses `spaces`.  I have wasted man-hours of time every time I see times and check everywhere in IDE settings and preferences for a setting  that can change this behavior without luck.  I just happened to notice the behavior I described above.  So the trick is, make sure the line above is indented with `spaces`!

(Edit:)
Wow.  I just noticed @E-riz posted an answer here about 10 years ago that says the same thing I said here.  I'm going to go follow that link in his answer!