# Editing eclipse line wrapper to one space instead of a indent

Tags: eclipse

I need to edit the format settings so it has a space instead of a indent.

```
    public final class ExampleClass
     extends AmazingClazz
     {

    }
```

I need it like the example above without changing the indent size.
How can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/407929/how-do-i-change-eclipse-to-use-spaces-instead-of-tabs (when you see indentation settings make editor use spaces only and set your number of spaces). BTW I am assuming that your example is not really correct since brackets which create a pair should be on same level of indentation.

Comment: No thats how I like it with an extends. :L

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't be done unless eclipse adds more features I guess.