# How to apply .editorconfig to an existing project in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, configuration, formatting, editorconfig

I have created a *.[editorconfig](https://editorconfig.org/)* file as shown below for IntelliJ IDEA.

```
# editorconfig.org

root = true

[*]
charset = utf-8
insert_final_newline = true
trim_trailing_whitespace = true
end_of_line = lf
indent_style = space
indent_size = 4

[*.js]
indent_size = 4

[{package.json}]
indent_style = space
indent_size = 4
```

How do I apply this code style to all the files in one go? Right now, I will open a file and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>l</kbd> which will do the job for that file, but is there a way to apply this as the configuration for all the application in IntelliJ IDEA 14?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Just enable it... ;)

(Unfortunately the setting is off by default.)

Menu *Settings* → *Editor* → *Code Style*.

Checkbox *Enable EditorConfig* support

[image]

Comment: Wow, the times I've struggled with my IDE code styles in different projects, trying to get the IntelliJ project settings in sync with my `.editorconfig`, getting crazy over the fact that "Set from .editorconfig" sometimes doesn't seem to work ... Only to now - thanks to you! - find out that there's a main setting to enable EditorConfig support. THANK YOU.

Answer (score 17):

Make sure to follow the steps in [Michal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50930969/2209007) first. If you want to retroactively apply this editorconfig to your existing files, do the following:

- I recommend committing all your files to Git, so you can reset to that commit if things did not go as planned.
- Make sure you have a `.editorconfig` you are happy with.
- In the `1:Project` sidepane, right-click on the folder you want to apply the `.editorconfig` to (e.g., the root folder of your project)
- Choose `Reformat Code`, which has the default shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>.
- Select "Include subdirectories". None of the other options are required. Then click "Run".

Your files now follow your `.editorconfig` file configuration.

[image: Right-click dropdown when clicking on a folder, with Reformat Code selected]

[image: Reformat Code dialog with only "Include subdirectories" checked]

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for, thank you!

Comment: This one worked for me! I did not see changes after simply editing the `.editorconfig` file

Answer (score -4):

If you added the file after project initialization.

You need to add the file *.editorconfig* on the root of the project.

Once happy with your file configuration, right-click and select synchronize '.editorconfig'.

Comment: Where is the 'synchronize .editorconfig' option you are referring to?