# EditorConfig for Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, whitespace, editorconfig

My project has *.editorconfig* file with:

```
[*.{js}]
charset = utf-8
indent_style = space
indent_size = 4
```

I thought this will force my Visual Studio Code to use indent style space with four spaces.

I installed the *EditorConfig for Visual Studio Code* extension from the list of extensions.

But still there isn't anything. My newly created files don't set automatically to the configured space style. What is the problem?

Comment: As this is plugin-related, not directly VScode-related, you should ask the plugin author(s) directly: https://github.com/editorconfig/editorconfig-vscode/issues

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think I found the solution. When I create the *.editorconfig* file with right-click on the folder structure sidebar in Visual Studio Code and select *Generate .editorconfig* (thus letting the plugin to create it), it works.

Click on the empty area below the files:

[image]

Comment: @doublnt You have to click on the empty space as in the picture above

Comment: This solution worked for me. I copied my existing `.editorconfig` contents to the clipboard, deleted the file, right-clicked and selected `Generate .editorconfig`, and then pasted back the contents into this new file. Then the plugin started working properly.

Comment: Remember to close the files and open them again. The settings will be working

Comment: If you try this and it seems like it worked (i.e. no error), but no file shows, you might need to refresh your explorer tree. VSCode might not pick up the newly added file straight away.

Comment: this solution is useless when it is for an entire team. for us intellij idea generated the .editorconfig and those who use vscode should use that one and not generate it. could you find anyway to tel vscode to start using the existing one?

Answer (score 4):

An update for croraf's answer.

**Step 1:**

Install the [EditorConfig for VS Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=EditorConfig.EditorConfig) extension from the marketplaces.

**Step 2:**

after installing the extension, right click inside the project explorer window (don't right click on any of the files and folders, just outside them)

**Step 3:**

click on the "Generate .editorconfig" option and .editorconfig fill will be generated

[image: editorconfig_SS]

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
root = true
[*.js]
indent_style = space
indent_size = 4
charset = utf-8
```

Comment: Why would that make a difference? An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48170568/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: Dv until you take Peter's suggestion.  Please improve your answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can also try this one. You can change to spaces if you like :)

```
root = true

[*]
end_of_line = lf
charset = utf-8
trim_trailing_whitespace = true
insert_final_newline = true
indent_style = tab
indent_size = 2

[*.{js,txt,md,css,html,php,py,json,yml,sass,pug}]
indent_style = tab
indent_size = 2

[*.{diff,md}]
trim_trailing_whitespace = false
```

Comment: Why would that make a difference? An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52201169/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score -9):

Visual Studio Code requires a plugin to use EditorConfig, so you need to install the plugin.

Comment: I said in the question "I installed EditorConfig for vs code extension from the list of extensions."