# How to get rid of Naming rule violation warning on Visual Studio CODE?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

How do I get rid of the nameing violation warning in Visual Studio Code.
The warning is as follows:
Naming rule violation: These words must begin with upper case characters:
[image]

I have looked in google but all the information I is about Visual Studio.
Changing the casing is not realy an option since I would have to change the casing in more than 20 files.

Comment: have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76828664/why-is-the-c-sharp-dev-kit-extension-giving-incorrect-redundant-warnings#comment135444371_76828664

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost, generally speaking you *should* be following best practices for naming conventions (readability, clarity, appropriate **and consistent** camel & pascal case, etc).

---

This seemingly depends on whether you're using Micro$hit's LSP or Omnisharp.

### Omnisharp

1. Open settings
2. search/go to: `@ext:ms-dotnettools.csharp omnisharp.Enable Editor Config Support`
3. Disable this option.

### LSP

I'm not entirely certain, since I reverted to Omnisharp the second it stopped being the default, however following other [links](https://www.reddit.com/r/vscode/comments/15jnnmi/psa_how_to_disable_roslyn_suggestionsblue/) has lead me to believe this is done by:

1. In VSCode, go to the far left panel that is right below the File menu.
2. Click on the Explorer tab.
3. Right-click a blank area in the Explorer tab and click "New File" in the popup menu.
4. Name the new file as .editorconfig (With the . at the beginning of the name)
5. Open .editorconfig, and paste in the following code:

```
[*.{cs,vb}]

dotnet_analyzer_diagnostic.category-Style.severity = none

dotnet_analyzer_diagnostic.category-CodeQuality.severity = none
```

6. Save the file, restart VSCode, and you are done!

---

To my understanding, the LSP method should work regardless of which language server is in use.